# How to use a struct as an operand of a conditional?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, operator-overloading, conditional-statements

I have a simple struct in C++11

```
struct a {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    ....
}
```

I would like to use this struct as if it is an scalar type itself, so I overloaded all operators.

One behaviour I can't find how to define is the use of a struct in an if statement:

```
a v = {1,2,3};
if (v) { }
```

Is there an operator that I can overload to enable this behaviour? I want the standard behaviour: if any bit is 1 in the struct it's true, else it's false.

Comment: +1 simple question that probably comes up more often than you think.

Answer (score 16):

Add an explicit boolean conversion:

```
struct a
{
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return a || b || c;
    }

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: If the author wants the code `if (v){}` to compile then the operator should not be explicit. Also he wants `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @AntonSavin Quite contrary, it *should* be explicit. `if()` performs a "contextual conversion to `bool`," which can call explicit operators just fine. Don't make stuff implicit unless you really need to.

Comment: @ Angew Ah sorry, learned something new about C++11 :) deleted my own answer.